# Сгруппировать строки по группам PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите. у меня есть база книг. У каждой книги есть издатель, он в базе повторяется. Как можно вывести таблицу по издательствам. Формата:

```
Издательство 1
-Книга 1
-Книга 2

Издательство 2
-Книга 1
-Книга 2
```

Запрос у меня такого типа

```
  $todb = $mysqli->query('SELECT *
  FROM book
  LEFT JOIN bookextend ON book.id = bookextend .book_id
  ORDER BY ID DESC');
```

Как я понимаю мне надо сделать два цикла `while`

Comment: было бы неплохо приложить структуру обеих таблиц

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам с ответом.
Сделал два цикла.

```
    $todb = $mysqli->query(' SELECT DISTINCT izdat FROM bookextend ORDER BY izdat DESC ');   
      while ($row = $todb->fetch_array())
      {
      echo $row['izdat'].'<br>';    
      $todb2 = $mysqli->query('SELECT *
      FROM book
      LEFT JOIN bookextend ON book.id = bookextend .book_id
      ORDER BY ID DESC');

       while ($row2 = $todb2->fetch_array())
      {
    echo $row2['book'];
      }
      }
```

Comment: не надо так. тащите все данные одним запросом как и было. Когда получите массив знаний пройдитесь по нему, и сгруппируйте элементы с одинаковыми издательствами. Потом двойной цикл уже используйте для вывода. Упорядочите выборку по издательству и потом названию. А при обработке проверяйте изменение издательство на итерации по отношению к предыдущему значению. В принципе тут вопросов про группировку достаточно много.